# NameError: name 'sort' is not defined when key=sort is used as parameter in sorted()

Tags: python, sorting

I am getting the following error on console

```
newList = sorted(l,key=sort) 
NameError: name 'sort' is not defined
```

after executing the following piece of code:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    l= [[input(), float(input())] for _ in range(int(input()))]
    print( l)
    new = sorted(l,key=sort)
    print(new)
```

From the [given](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sorted-function-python/) article I learned that `key` parameter in `sorted()` can use user/inbuilt Python methods. I am trying to sort my list alphabetically so I passed `key=sort` with an understanding that it will sort my list alphabetically.

Please help me out where am I going wrong here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`sorted()` function has an optional parameter called `key` which takes a **function as its value**. This **key function transforms each element before sorting, it takes the value and returns 1 value which is then used within sort instead of the original value**.

Example:
If there is a list of tuples,
`li = [('p1', 20), ('p2', 10), ('p3', 30)]`
and you want to sort the elements of the list in such a way that the resulting order is as follows:
Ouptut: `li = [('p2', 10), ('p1', 20), ('p3', 30)]`
Then, all you need to do is, sort the tuples, based on the 2nd element in each tuple.

**To do so, we need to use a custom method, which will be applied to each element and the elements will be sorted based on the representative of each element(i.e KEY)**.

Hence, the syntax to the same will be as follows:
`sorted(li, key=lambda x: x[1])`

**Edit:**

Sort is in itself a function, which is used to arrange elements in a specific order. But, it cannot be used to extract a representative (i.e a KEY) for each element in the list.

Comment: Maybe change your example so it doesn't work if you _don't_ use the key function, as right now simply doing `sorted(li)` will yield the same result.

Comment: I see! I've made the necessary changes. @L3viathan

Answer (score 2):

Well, `sort` is not a user/built-in Python function. It is a method on lists, but, not a name accessible globally. Even if you would use it (through `key=list.sort`), it would not give you your desired result, as the key function is used to transform each *element* before sorting.

By default (without specifying the `key` parameter), `sorted` should already sort strings  alphabetically (sort of), same with lists containing lists with a string as the first item. If you want to sort `"A"` and `"a"` together (as well as `"Z"` and `"z"`), you could use the key function `str.lower`, but you would need to apply that only to the first element of your inner lists:

```
new = sorted(l, key=lambda x: x[0].lower())
```